# How do I parse the data I achieved through splitting a string into Int values in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, parseint

I split a string which is a password entered by the user to only return back digits. I need to make sure those digits they entered aren't certain digits. But first, I need to take the data that comes back and turn them into an int so I can compare.

```
public static boolean checkPassword(String password){
      String digitsRegrex = "[a-zA-Z]+";
      int upPass;

      String [] splitPass = password.split("[a-zA-Z]+");
      for(String pass : splitPass){
         try{
            upPass = Integer.parseInt(pass);
         }
         catch (NumberFormatException e){
            upPass = 0;
         }       
         System.out.println(upPass);
      }  
      return true;   
  }
```

When I run the program I get back the 0 (and the digits in the string password) in the catch, so the try isn't working I guess?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, you set `upPass` to 0 when you encounter a substring that do not contain any digits. These are **empty strings**. This happens when the password does not start with a digit.

You should be ignoring it as you need only digits.

Example: `abcd12356zz33` - when you split using the regex `[a-zA-Z]+` you get `""`, `"123456"`, and `"33"`. When you attempt to convert the first empty string to a number, you get a `NumberFormatException`.

```
for(String pass : splitPass){
    if (!pass.isEmpty()) {
        try {
            upPass = Integer.parseInt(pass);
            System.out.println(upPass);
            //Validate upPass for the combination of numbers
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
checkPassword("abcd12356zz33")
```

prints

```
12356
33
```

Comment: whats the difference between pass.matches("[0-9]+") and the isEmpty you're using now? Is it because I am already splitting it?

Comment: I have removed that part. Now, I'm checking if empty as the original regex (`[A-Za-z]+`) already ensures that there won't be any letters.